# how can i access column from subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

```
  select u.phone, u.email , t.to_address (error from this)
  from user_accounts u 
  where u.id 
  in 
   (select w.user_id 
   from wallets w 
   where w.id 
   in 
     (
     select t.wallet_id 
     from withdraws t 
     where t.to_address 
     in 
     ('1F6o1fZZ7', 'pJDtRRnyhDN')))
```

I want to get the column `to_address` from subquery. How can I get it in postgresql?

I try assign 'AS' for subquery but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

A join returns a result table constructed from data from multiple tables. You can also retrieve the same result table using a sub query. A sub query is simply a SELECT statement within another select statement.

```
select u.phone, u.email , t.to_address (
 from user_accounts u 
INNER JOIN wallets w  ON u.id= w.user_id 
INNER JOIN withdraws t ON t.wallet_id =w.id 
  where t.to_address  in ('1F6o1fZZ7', 'pJDtRRnyhDN')
```

Answer (score 0):

use join with all the table, you dont need any subquery

```
 select u.phone, u.email , ww.to_address 
 from user_accounts u  left join wallets w  on u.id=w.user_id
  left jon withdraws ww on w.id=ww.wallet_id
where ww.to_address in ('1F6o1fZZ7', 'pJDtRRnyhDN')
```

You can not access `t.address` because that column inside `in` condition.
I used `left` join but it seems it will be `inner join` type because you used filter `in ('1F6o1fZZ7', 'pJDtRRnyhDN')` though after applying where condition it also behave like inner join

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you're trying using subquery. When you want records from different tables and they have a unique column in common that connects them then You should do it using a `JOIN`.

**Sometimes** (Not all cases) `IN` can cause performance problems, so you should consider knowing more about different types of `JOINS`(https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Check the link for comparison:
[Inner join versus doing a where in clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626905/inner-join-versus-doing-a-where-in-clause)

**About the Query:**

```
SELECT
  u.phone, u.email , t.to_address (error from this)
FROM
  user_accounts u 
  INNER JOIN wallets w ON u.id = w.id
  INNER JOIN withdraws t ON t.wallet_id = w.id
WHERE
  t.to_address IN ('1F6o1fZZ7', 'pJDtRRnyhDN')
```

Comment: You have a reference to a SQL Server performance question, but this question is tagged Postgres.

Comment: Additionally: not every IN condition can be rewritten as a JOIN. Those are two different things